# The limit set of consecutive applications of linear transforms to the single segment

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrences, lebesgue-measure

**Problem.** Consider $n$ positive integers $1 < a_1\le \ldots \le a_n$ and $I = \left[\frac{1}{a_n - 1}, \frac{1}{a_1 - 1}\right]$. For each $a_k$ define the linear transform $\phi_k\colon x\mapsto \frac{x + 1}{a_k}$ then we have $\phi_k(I)\subset I$. The family of nested sets is defined recursively by
$$
S_0 = I, \qquad S_m = \bigcup_{k = 1}^n\phi_k(S_{m - 1})\subset S_{m - 1}.
$$
What can be said about the $S_{\infty} = \bigcap S_k$ in terms of the initial sequence $a_i$?

**Sparse case**. If $a = \{2,3\}$ then $I = [1/2, 1]$ and $S_k$ have the following structure (sets $S_0,\ldots S_3$ from bottom to top are drawn with colored horizontal segments and dotted lines indicate the images of endpoint os segments in $S_k$ in the set $S_{k + 1}$.)
[image]
When $a$ consists of exactly two numbers then $S_k$ is always a union of $2^{k}$ disjoint segments and $S_{\infty}$ is a cantor-type set of Lebesgue measure $0$. More generally, if for each $k$ the segment $\phi_k(I)$ and $\phi_{k + 1}(I)$ do not intersect then $S_k$ have $|a|^k$ components and $S_{\infty}$ is also a Cantor-type set. In terms of $a_i$ this can be written as $a_{k + 1}> \frac{r + 1}{l + 1}a_k$, where $I = [l,r] = \left[\frac{1}{a_n - 1}, \frac{1}{a_1 - 1}\right]$.

**Dense case.** If $a = \{2,3,4\}$ then $I= [1/3, 1]$ and for each $S_k = I$.[image: second example]

This situation occurs when for each $k$ the segments $\phi_k(I)$ and $\phi_{k + 1}(I)$  intersect. This can be rewritten as $a_{k + 1} \le \frac{r + 1}{l + 1}a_k$, where $I = [l,r] = \left[\frac{1}{a_n - 1}, \frac{1}{a_1 - 1}\right]$. For example this situation happens when $a = \{N, N + 1, \ldots , N^2\}$ but not when $a = \{N, N + 1, \ldots , N^2 - 1\}$.

**General case.** If $a = \{3,4,5,6\}$ then $I = [1/5, 1/2]$. In this situation $S_0, S_1, S_2, \ldots$ consist of $1, 2, 6, 20, 73, 274,\ldots$ connected components respectively.

[image: third exmaple]

**Conjectures**.

- If $S_{\infty} \neq I$ then $\operatorname{int}( S_{\infty}) = \emptyset$.
- If $S_{\infty} \neq I$ then the Lebesgue measure of $S_{\infty}$ equals 0.
- The same questions for not necessary integer sequence $a$.

**Background**. This question is connected to this [old olympiad problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1153063p5462973) and the set $S_{\infty}$ is related to the set of numbers $x$ such that $x$ can be represented as $x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n_k}$, where for each $k$ the ratio $\frac{n_{k + 1}}{n_k}$ equals to one of $a_i$.